# IPhone 6 Camera Stopped Working after 8.4 Update

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

After updating to 8.4 two weeks ago, both cameras stopped working.  The camera app shows a black screen and once you press any of the buttons the rest of them stop doing anything.  The shutter button 'clicks' but does nothing, then the settings randomly disappear.  No other modes work, though I can scroll through them.  I can not change to the front camera. Other apps that use the camera will open, but I only get grey screens. (Some crash right away.)
I've restarted, updated to 8.4.1, but nothing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the Apple forum. Try this

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203040

Comment: Good answer, I upvoted it, but should the cameras still not work, the OP may just have to wait for bug fixes in iOS 9. It will be released on September 16, so that's not too long of a wait.